# Smooth Scrolling with only vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, smooth-scrolling

I have always used this jQuery script for smooth scrolling:

```
var root = $('html, body');
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
root.animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
}, 1000);
return false;
});
```

How can I do this with vanilla JavaScript? I have tried this:

```
document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

But it doesn't work with Safari, which is a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) safari doesn't support options parameters on `scrollIntoView` so you'll need to find another method. I suggest taking a look at [this alternative](https://vigu-madurai.medium.com/solved-alternate-to-the-default-scrollintoview-8da76e083066).